# I want to install laravel project on localhost but i am facing error how to fix it?

Tags: laravel

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public\index.php on line 24

Comment: you get that error when? seems you pulled in a project and didn't tell composer to install the dependencies

Comment: actully i have already installed composer

Comment: you might have composer but you didn't tell composer to install the dependencies for this project you grabbed

Comment: how to install  ? please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of this "project" on the command line and type `composer install` to have composer install the dependencies for this "project".